# How to add a second search path for subdomain, using sphinx

Tags: search

Just wondering if anyone has had any success in implementing a second search path, for a subdomain, using [sphinx search module](https://www.drupal.org/project/sphinxsearch) in Drupal?

Any best practice advice, is much obliged!